# Parent directory in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, directory

I have project with name '`XMLparser`'. In project have one folder with name '`XML`' which contains the file '`database.xml`' When I try to get directory to database Java show error.

Java error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at XMLparser.main(XMLparser.java:24)
```

I try to get directory with this code:

```
Document document = builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("../xml/database.xml"));
```

Project tree:

```
XMLparser
  src
   - (default package)
     - XMLparser.java (My code is here)

  JRE System Library

  xml
    - database.xml (This is the xml file)
```

What need to type here ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("`HERE`") to work?

Comment: The xml directory is outside your classpath. Add it or move it under the src directory.

Comment: I think you have to create input stream from path. Becase you're trying to call getResource from nonRecource directory. How to get path is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770384/parent-parent-directory-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if you won't add "/xml/database.xml" in your "src" folder:

```
final String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(workingDirectory + "/xml/database.xml");
document = builder.parse(in);
..
```

.

Answer (score 1):

You can not go to the root folder of your application

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the first part like this:

```
document = builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("xml/database.xml"));
```

Your xml folder is in the root of your project folder this is where getSystemResourceAsStream looks if I am not mistaken.