# Java class loading resources

Tags: java, resources, classloader

I'm having a class `MailSend` which needs to get `.png` resource, but I can't read it, tried using classloader but it goes to another directory from jar. The closes directory I get from using `MailSend.class.getResource("")` but the resource is two folders up I tried using `../..` but if gives me exception is there an alternative to go up or I need to use something else?

Comment: Is the png you are looking for in a parent or child folder?

Comment: MailSend class is in Test/services/mail/MailSend and resource is in Test/resources/images/logo.png

Comment: Can this be to any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770384/parent-parent-directory-in-java

Comment: Yeah i found the answer in one of comments. Thank you :)